# IP address + domain name

Tags: networking, rdns

I have an IP address, xx.xx.xx.xx, for which ping works. But when I do an [nslookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup) for that IP address it is failing. Is there a way to find the domain name of the machine with the IP address xx.xx.xx.xx?

Answer (score 4):

1. The machine will not necesserily have a domain name.
2. Try traceroute

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is via a reverse DNS lookup. However, if you are saying that `nslookup` is failing then (unless there is a local issue with you having bad DNS servers listed on your local machine), then a reverse lookup will not work.

The various tools that other posters have mentioned, all ultimately do exactly the same the nslookup will do from your machine. They do a reverse DNS lookup via the "in-addr.arpa" address range (this is a special domain reserved in DNS for reverse lookups).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a "reverse DNS lookup". Try [this one](http://remote.12dt.com/) online, or Google further for other options.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's called Reverse DNS! Perhaps try: http://remote.12dt.com/

Also consider DNSStuff: http://www.dnsstuff.com/ great website for troubleshooting DNS issues.

Comment: I doubt this will work. nslookup is doing exactly this type of reverse lookup when yu type in an ip address. Unless there is a local issue on the client with DNS entries, it will yield the same results.

Answer (score 0):

In order for an IP address to resolve to a hostname, a PTR record must exist in DNS.  For example:

```
234.9.96.65.in-addr.arpa. 3570  IN      PTR     h00c0f06bacf1.ne.client2.attbi.com.
```

The ISP that owns the netblock including your IP (or its delegated zone authority) must set this up.